# Git checkout prematurely ended with Bus error (core dumped)

Tags: git

I am using ubuntu and recently I was trying to update git from my current version 2.28 to the latest release 2.29.2 using the instructions here https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git and I failed to install "docbook2X"  which is required to complete the installation of this git version.

so my problem now is my git seems to be not working properly now. I have a repository on my computer where if I try checking out to another branch it fails. so basically as it is trying to do "git checkout" it suddenly stops and returns the  'Bus error (core dumped)'

So when I check with "git status" some of the files look to be modified by the git checkout command but git has not changed the repository

so I delete the .git/index.lock then run git restore. to restore then clean the directory again repeat the process and still get the same result. So basically I am stuck on one branch and can't checkout to another.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: This indicates that something is very wrong - either a bug in Git, or something badly wrong with the computer (hardware or software: could be bad memory, a bad library, etc). If you built your own Git from scratch, you can try building it in debug mode and see if you can track down the problem that way. Usually most people just install a prebuilt Git package. Is there some particular reason you need 2.29.2 instead of 2.28?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with one git repository because other git repositories seem to be working fine. There seem to be a number of error files within this repository that I am not sure of how to fix them. Also, I needed the 2.29.2 version because of some tool I am using but it looks like it also did not get installed when I check git --version I am still on 2.28 but the installation process didnot return any errors.

Comment: Ah, this is probably a mis-installation then: if you told 2.29.2 to install itself, and partly overwrote the 2.28 system version with 2.29.2, the 2.28 versions you're running are invoking 2.29.2 pieces to get things done and are confused by their responses. Note that *when* you build Git, you tell it where to expect itself to be installed; when you later install Git, you tell it where to install. You must be consistent with these two steps.

Comment: So do you think I should try to locate the installation files for git 2.29.2 and uninstall it? What is your recommendation to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, if you're really set on running 2.29.2, build it again and re-install it, but build it (and install it) with the configuration that the Ubuntu folks use, whatever that is.

Comment: I want to revert back to the old git 2.28 but I am not sure how to fix it now.  What I am thinking is to just delete this particular repository and re-clone it but I have some  branches (work on this repo) that I do not want to lose. nomally I would just try to back up the .git folder but in this case this folder has a coulple of broken files so my question is how do I copy my current branches to this new cloned repo

Comment: Ah - in that case, use `apt` to de-install and re-install the default version of Git. After de-installing, see if there are any Git binaries installed; those will be remnants of the 2.29.2 installation, which you can get rid of before the reinstall with apt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: This is how I solved this problem.**

1. I deleted the old repository luckily all my branches had a remote origin so I didn't lose any of my work.
2. I recloned the repo.
3. I then fetched each of the branches individually.
4. After fetching each branch I then checkout to that particular branch to confirm I could now checkout to that branch without getting the bus error.

   ```
   git clone the_new_repo/
   cd the_new_repo/
   git fetch "https://github.com/my_username/project.git" "Branch_To_be_fetched"
   git checkout Branch_that_was_fetched
   ```

Luckily again all my remote versions were up to date with the local version changes so I did not lose any work. I believe the problem was as a result of damaged files within the `.git` folder. I couldn't find a way to debug these errors so I opted for the `delete and reclone the repo` solution.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall/Remove git and install it again.

Step 1:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove git
```

Step 2:

```
sudo apt install git-core
```